# What is the acceptable level of concurvity?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I got the following concurvity values as a result of a GAM model.

[image]

Are they considered high or low? I don't know what is the acceptable value.

Answer (score 6):

This is a late bump to a relatively old question, but may be of help to future visitors.

In Noam Ross' course on GAMs, [GAMs in R](https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/), Chapter 2, section 10 "checking concurvity" says that observing a value over 0.8 for the worst case requires closer inspection of the model. So in the image you pasted there's only one variable over 0.8 (`VV_PROM_S60`), but there are many very close to that threshold, so you may want to check those too. The suggested way to have a closer look at the model is by using `concurvity(model, full = FALSE)` and carefully analyzing the pairwise concurvities.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to get more clarity on this as well, but I did find one paper (Tree traits inﬂuence response to ﬁre severity in the western Oregon Cascades, USA; 2019) that used the `mgcv` package where the authors used a cutoff of 0.3.  It sounded like they applied that cutoff to all three measures of concurvity.  Of course, even they said it was an arbitrary cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

Another source, from a doctoral dissertation *Multi-city time series analyses of air pollution and mortality data using generalized geoadditive mixed models*
by Lung-Chang Chien. Free online [access](https://cdr.lib.unc.edu/concern/dissertations/h702q689j?locale=en).

> So far, there is no strict criterion to identify the level of concurvity which can
> severely affect model fitting. Ramsay et al. (2003a) suggested using 0.5 to be the cutoff
> point. If the level of concurvity in nonparametric or semiparametric models is greater than
> 0.5, it is necessary to seek in order to eliminate or reduce this problem.